# Refresh powerpivot data connections using power automate desktop

Tags: powerbi, power-automate

I was wondering if this is possible? In short, I have a set of data being updated based on atomsvc file/ connections. Since I can't get that data directly in PowerBi, I us PowerPivot as intermediary.  I set pp to autorefresh the data when I open the file and I want to not have to do that; rather schedule PowerAutomate  desktop to do that.

And while that seems easy enough and I can do it, whenever PA opens PP, the data connections don't get refreshed. I wonder if I'm doing something wrong or if there is a different way to do that (get atomsvc into powerbi on a daily basis)?

Comment: Can't you just refresh your dataset using the Power BI connector in Power Automate Cloud?   https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/refresh-your-power-bi-dataset-using-microsoft-flow/

Comment: Thank you Ethan! The main issue is with one data source which comes via atomsvc. To my knowledge ( certainly limited), powerBi does not support this type of file so I need to use PowerPivot as intermediary as stated above. In other words , to be able to refresh my data in powerBi , i need first to refresh my power-pivot tables whihc are use as a source for powerBi. Does it make sense ?